# How to return a non null column from OracleDB

Tags: sql, oracle, birt

I am creating a birt report on eclipse and I need to put a date filter.
I have more than 1 field with date in the report, and some of them are null.
The problem is: how do I use the correct date(not null) to use as parameter for the filter? Im trying to do something like this:

```
select
case 
when D___1 is null then
D___2
when D___2 is null then
D___3
when D___3 is null then
D___4
when D___4 is null then
D___5
end as data
```

And then this would return a valid date and I would use as filter. But this doesnt seem to work. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: == is not an operator in SQL, and checking for null should be using IS NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to display the first non-null column out of D1, D2, D3, D4, D5? If so, you may be better off with `COALESCE(D1, D2, D3, D4, D5)`.

Your case statement won't work as you expect it to, because

a) "==" isn't valid syntax in Oracle

b) the comparison `<something> = null` (and correspondingly, `<something> != null`) always returns null - ie. it is neither true nor false. Instead, you should be checking for: `<something> is null` (and conversely: `<something> is not null`).

c) your logic is incomplete - you're checking for what to do if D1 through D5 is null, but not what happens if D1 (or D2 or ...) isn't null.

Assuming you're wanting the first non-null value, this ought to give you an idea of how you could do it, both with the coalesce and with the case logic:

```
with sample_data as (select 1 col1, null col2, null col3 from dual union all
                     select null col1, 2 col2, null col3 from dual union all
                     select null col1, null col2, 3 col3 from dual union all
                     select null col1, 4 col2, 5 col3 from dual union all
                     select 6 col1, 7 col2, 8 col3 from dual union all
                     select 9 col1, null col2, 10 col3 from dual)
select col1,
       col2,
       col3,
       coalesce(col1, col2, col3) first_non_null_coalesce,
       case when col1 is not null then col1
            when col2 is not null then col2
            when col3 is not null then col3
       end first_non_null_case_logic
from   sample_data;

      COL1       COL2       COL3 FIRST_NON_NULL_COALESCE FIRST_NON_NULL_CASE_LOGIC
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------------------- -------------------------
         1                                             1                         1
                    2                                  2                         2
                               3                       3                         3
                    4          5                       4                         4
         6          7          8                       6                         6
         9                    10                       9                         9
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Im new in the software field and your example helped me a lot! We need more answers like this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [COALESCE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm#SQLRF00617) function. It returns the first "not NULL" value from given list.

Would be like this:

```
COALESCE(D___1, D___2, D___3, D___4, D___5) as DATA
```